# estimating weights in lattice recursive least squares (LRLS)

Tags: regression, least-squares, kalman-filter, signal-processing

I'm struggling to estimate the weights (W) from the forward and backward prediction coefficients (*k*) in Lattice recursive least squares ([Lattice-RLS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter#Lattice_recursive_least_squares_filter_(LRLS))). The standard recursive least squares (RLS) normally yields weights, as shown [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursive_least_squares_filter) and in many books, but the information on how to estimate these same weights (or how to take advantage of the forward and backward prediction coefficients) in Lattice-RLS to regenerate the desired output from the input is quite rare or I haven't came across them yet. Most sources I have came across skip the part that estimates the weights in Lattice-RLS. Any help or advice on how to recover the weights in Lattice-RLS or how to efficiently use the forward and backward prediction coefficients to regenerate the desired output from the input is deeply appreciated.